# Fatal error: Call to a member function SetFetchMode() on a non-object error

Tags: php, adodb

I was using ADODB to fetch data. I get error like this:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function SetFetchMode() on a non-object
```

and this is my code:

```
function createAdodbConnection($fetchMode = ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC) {
        $self = DbManager::_instance();
        $conn = &ADONewConnection($self->getDsn());
        $conn->SetFetchMode($fetchMode);
        return $conn;
    }
```

Comment: what does $self->getDsn() returns? ps: sorry, my previous comment was totally wrong

Comment: It returns this : mysql://root:@localhost/Project

Comment: What is `&ADONewConnection` supposed to do?

Comment: It initiates a new Connection class for a specific database driver.